# помощь в php выводе ошибки

Tags: php

Есть такой код notfound.php:

```
      $error_type = 'default';
$request    = ( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : NULL;
$query      = explode('/', $request);
if ( is_array($query) ) {
    foreach ( $query as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value == 'error' ) {
            $error_type = ( isset($query[$key+1]) ) ? $query[$key+1] : NULL;
        }
    }
}

switch ( $error_type ) {
    case 'video_private':
        $message = $lang['error.video_private'];
        break;
    case 'album_private':
        $message =  $lang['error.album_private'];
        break; default:
            $message =  $lang['error.unexpected_error'];
            break;
    }
```

отдается только default сообщение error.unexpected_error, url выглядит site.ru/notfound/video_private
и должно отдаваться  error.video_private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо эту строку переделать

```
if ( is_array($query) ) {
    foreach ( $query as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value == 'error' ) {
            $error_type = ( isset($query[$key+1]) ) ? $query[$key+1] : NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

в

```
if (is_array($query)) {
    $error_type = end($query);
}
```

Иначе у вас `error_type` либо `null`, либо `default`.